# How to put reload option in ui-sref markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

How can I specify the `reload` option in a `ui-sref` markup? All the examples I see use the javascript function directly.

```
<a ui-sref="app.editPost({new:true}, {reload:true})">new post</a>
```

Doesn't seem to work. Do I have to create a scope controller function to wrap that `reload` option instead?

I've also tried some answers below and it doesn't seem to work with the Ionic framework. Link to code pen sample below:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LERqeb

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `ui-sref-opts`. Here you go:

```html
<a ui-sref="app.editPost({new:true})"
   ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}">new post</a>
```

https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/0.3.1/index.html#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.  I tried adding the  ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}" and it doesn't seem to reload my ionic controller when I click (it navigates but doesn't trigger a re-run of the controller) - do you think it's an ionic issue or an angular issue or me not understanding reload correctly

Comment: This is working at my side. So what do you want to achieve from reload?

Comment: Which version of angular ui-router you are using?

Comment: If you are using version < 0.2.11 then add `notify: true` to your reload options. I've modified the same on answer.

Comment: I'm using the latest ionic which uses angular-ui-router 0.2.13.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the editPost controller refresh to initialized new blanks when you click new on a global side menu link, so that you don't have stale old post state variables when creating a fresh new post.

Comment: I've created a code pen with the example behviour - try filling in the check-in form, then navigate away and come back using the menu, the old form values are still there  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LERqeb

Comment: Hey @MonkeyBonkey, after spending half an hour on your issue, I got to knwo that its by implementation. Ionic caches the state & does not destroy the scope but just disconnects it. So simple fix of your issue is to use `cache: false` inside your state configuration. Cheers!

Comment: I've updated the example for you: Please see line 21 in JS section of http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoRzjN. Only line 21 is newly added according to doc. See caching in http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Regarding the notify option, it's not whitelisted so won't ever work I don't believe. I've created an issue here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1875