# How to re-run the controller every time you navigate to the corresponding view/state?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a view that is linked up to a controller:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  ...
</div>
```

the controller:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope',
  // Some code here that calls a webservice and updates the scope
]);
```

When the controller initially runs, it calls a webservice, returns the data and binds it to the scope. It works great. However when I navigate to another view/state using `ui-sref` or `$state.go()` and I navigate *back* to this view, the controller doesn't call the webservice again.

Is there a way to make sure that every time the state lands on this view and controller, the controller is re-run so to speak?

Comment: in view, set cache false.

Comment: you can set cache false in route also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic by default caches view and controller execution to improve performance. You can disable it with `cache: false`:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
});
```

Or you can disable it at URL level using `ui-sref-opts` [How to put reload option in ui-sref markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690834/how-to-put-reload-option-in-ui-sref-markup/27690880#27690880)

See [Caching](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) docs.

Comment: Brilliant! This is exactly what I was looking for