# controller only initialized once even if `$stateparams` changed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I've recently started working with the *Ionic Framework* (and therefore with *Angular.js* as well) and I ran into a problem with the *Angular UI Router*: One of the states I registered is not re-initialized when one of its `$stateParams` changes. At first I thought it happens because the state is abstract and has children, so it is never activated directly - but even when I changed it to be non-abstract and one of the "deepest" states (i.e. a leaf when seeing the states within a tree structure), the problem persists. The weird thing is that it seems not to happen on other states.

I have tried different approaches and read the documentation carefully, but I could not find the cause for the issue.

The following is the code I use to register the states. The state `app.festival` is the one I'm having the issue with:

- when I link to the `app.festival.overview` state for the first time, for example with URL `/festival/33/overview`, the the state's controller as well as its abstract parent controller for `app.festival` are initialized correctly
- but then, when I go back somewhere else, and then link to something like `/festival/21/overview`, only this state's controller is re-initialized, but not its abstract parent controller (although the parameter for the `festivalId` is part of it and should trigger a reload I suppose)
- this results in the actual festival data (referenced by `festivalId`) which is managed by the `app.festival` state remains the same throughout the entire app because basically it just initializes one "instance" of the controller for `app.festival` regardless of different `$stateParams`

The reason I need that structure is that there needs to be a whole section of pages (states) that deal with a single festival (which should be managed by the `app.festival` state).

```
$stateProvider

.state( 'app', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'appContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state( 'app.general', {
    url: '/general',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'mainContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/sections/general.html',
            controller: 'GeneralCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state( 'app.festival', {
    url: '/festival/{festivalId:int}',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'mainContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/sections/festival.html',
            controller: 'FestivalCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state( 'app.general.festivals', {
    url: '/festivals',
    views: {
        'generalContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/general-festivals.html',
            controller: 'GeneralFestivalsCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state( 'app.general.events', {
    url: '/events',
    views: {
        'generalContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/general-events.html',
            controller: 'GeneralEventsCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state( 'app.general.event', {
    url: '/events/{eventId:int}',
    views: {
        'generalContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/general-event.html',
            controller: 'GeneralEventCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state( 'app.festival.overview', {
    url: '/overview',
    views: {
        'festivalContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/festival-overview.html',
            controller: 'FestivalOverviewCtrl'
        }
    }
});

.state( 'app.festival.guide', {
    url: '/guide',
    views: {
        'festivalContent': {
            templateUrl: 'views/pages/festival-guide.html',
            controller: 'FestivalGuideCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

It would be great if anyone could help me out there as I've put quite some hours into researching the issue, but have not found a solution yet. If you need more insight into specific parts of the code, I'll gladly post it here as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-run the controller every time you navigate to the corresponding view/state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33384826/how-to-re-run-the-controller-every-time-you-navigate-to-the-corresponding-view-s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of Ionic. It by default caches view and controller execution to improve performance. You can disable it with `cache: false`:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
});
```

Or you can disable it at URL level using `ui-sref-opts` [how to put reload option in ui-sref markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690834/how-to-put-reload-option-in-ui-sref-markup/27690880#27690880)

See [Caching](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) docs.