# AngularJS controller doesn't work after first refresh page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-controller

I'm using AngularJS for my hybrid Ionic app.

**My controller:**

```
.controller('SubmitCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("this just work for only refreshing the page!);
});
```

Only for each refreshing the page, `console.log` works fine, but when I **switch to other states**, and came back to `submit` state (without refreshing the page), `console.log` doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: it is bcoz o page cache.

Comment: @Ved So, what should I do?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: No it's because of state cache. UI-Router cache controller states.

Comment: @vahidnajafi check my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [controller only initialized once even if \`$stateparams\` changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811303/controller-only-initialized-once-even-if-stateparams-changed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is bcoz Ionic cache your page.
Try this

```
  <ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
      ...
    </ion-view>
```

or,

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

Source: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Is this only a feature of ui-router with ionic or does ui-router itself support this as well?

Comment: @Aides this is a question for me too.

Comment: Yes, this feature is supported by ui-router

Comment: I found this answer for angularjs (without ionic). But I haven't tested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690834/how-to-put-reload-option-in-ui-sref-markup/27690880#27690880

Answer (score 1):

Though @Ved has answered this question perfectly, disable ionic view cache is not a graceful resolution. If you just want some parts of a page controller to be executed whenever you enter this page, maybe you should make use of ionic view lifecycle:

```
.controller('SubmitCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
    //code in this block will be executed every time before you enter in
    console.log("this just work for only refreshing the page!);
  });
});
```

More information about ionic view lifecycle, please refer http://www.gajotres.net/understanding-ionic-view-lifecycle/ and http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/. Hope this will help, regards!

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is also awesome.